# Transform coordinates from moving domain into fixed domain but using coordinate-filled 3D array

Tags: elastix, elastix-itk

All,

I have two images, one is X(moving) and one is F(fixed). I have registered the moving image to the fixed and I get a transform parameter map (T), according to the manual, this T is the matrix from fixed to moving domain, and by applying transformix, I will get T^(-1)(x), x is the moving images, right?

Now I am trying to transform coordinates from moving domain to fixed domain, I figured out how to use transformix point set but it took too long to run compared with transforming an image. So I want to create 3 separate coordinate maps of x,y, and z then directly apply transformix instead of transformix_point_set. The result images should be the transformed coordinates.

My questions:

Does this method I describe work? Does Elastix accept any other data type that did not consider spacing and origin? (I looked at bmp but it is 2d only).

I appreciate any help you can provide.

I copied the header of the moving image to each of the coordinate maps. Then run itk transformix, but the results are a bunch of float points instead of an integer and the float does not look like a physics coordinate either. I am not sure whether this is correct or not.